# Prove that the map $x:(u^1,u^2)\mapsto ((2+\cos u^1)\cos u^2,(2+\cos u^1)\sin u^2,\sin u^1)$ is injective on the domain $-\pi<u^1,u^2<\pi$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, differential-geometry

So, like we usually prove injectivity, I consider my two points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which I denote $(u^1,u^2)$ and $(v^1,v^2)$, and I'm trying to conclude that if $\underbrace{x(u^1,u^2)=x(v^1,v^2)}_{(*)}$, then our two points are the same. From the third entry in $(*)$ we have $\sin u^1=\sin v^1$ and in our domain this means that either $u^1+v^1=\pm \pi$ or $u^1=v^1$. Now I consider case 1: $u^1+v^1= \pi$ which implies $\cos v^1=-\cos u^1$. Hence, from our first two entries in our equality (*) we have 
$$\cos u^1(\cos u^2+\cos v^2)=2(\cos v^2-\cos u^2)$$ and
$$\cos u^1(\sin u^2+\sin v^2)=2(\sin v^2-\sin u^2).$$
My problem is I have no idea how to get $u^1=v^1=\pi/2$ and $u^2=v^2$ from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok! You have the third components equal, so $\sin u^1=\sin v^1$.
From the first and second components equality:
$$(2+\cos u^1)\cos u^2=(2+\cos v^1)\cos v^2   \space\space\space\space\space\space\space(1)$$ and $$(2+\cos u^1)\sin u^2=(2+\cos v^1)\sin v^2\space\space\space\space\space\space\space (2)$$
Now put them into the square and add:
$$(2+\cos u^1)^2=(2+\cos v^1)^2$$
$$|2+\cos u^1|=|2+\cos v^1|$$
Both $(2+\cos u^1)$ and $(2+\cos v^1)$ are positive, so they are equal:
$$2+\cos u^1=2+\cos v^1$$ or $$\cos u^1=\cos v^1$$
So, $\sin$ and $\cos$ of $u^1$ and $v^1$ are equal respectively, so $u^1=v^1$.
Hence, from the equations (1) and (2), we can conclude the same for $u^2$ and $v^2$